# Symfony + Doctrine + MD5 issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to use the sql function MD5 in my Symfony bundle so I added the file (https://gist.github.com/Basster/2774738) in \MyCompany\MyBundle\DQL\MD5Function.

Then I changed my config.yml file :

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        # Added configuration for MD5 function
        entity_managers:
            default:
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                        MD5: MyCompany\MyBundle\DQL\MD5Function
```

But I have the following error :

InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 309: Unrecognized options "naming_strategy, auto_mapping" under "doctrine.orm"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You mix the one entity manager configuration and the multi entity manager one.

You should use:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        # Added configuration for MD5 function
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MD5: MyCompany\MyBundle\DQL\MD5Function
```

or:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                # Added configuration for MD5 function
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                        MD5: MyCompany\MyBundle\DQL\MD5Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can create your own class to do that like explained here [How to create and use custom built doctrine DQL function in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/cgo2/how-to-create-and-use-custom-built-doctrine-dql-function-in-symfony). Funny enough the example is based on SHA1 so you can just simply change the SH1 to MD5, like I did below.

**Your custom MD5 class**

```
namespace Football\FrontendBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class Md5 extends FunctionNode
{
    public $value;

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->value = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'MD5(' . $this->value->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }
}
```

**Register it in config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                MD5: Football\FrontendBundle\DQL\Md5
```

**And use it in your repository like this**

```
namespace Football\FrontendBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

class CountryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneCountryBy($id)
    {
        return
            $this
                ->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->select('c, MD5(c.code) AS code')
                ->where('c.id = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
    }
}
```